# Lacie External Hardrive doesn't show up on Mac or in Disk utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, external-disk

My lacie hard drive was making some strange clicking noises when I put it in  my mac. I have also tried this in a PC. It now is just not showing up in the devices and also when I try to access it in Disk Utility. It did show up once in Disk Utility but it did not allow me to press first aid. Now it is not showing up at all. I have tried different cables to connect it to the port too. It now is not making noise, it is silent with the orange light flashing but nothing happening.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Spinning disk drives fail, and its clicking-then-silence and invisibility to the host computers both indicate that this one has given up the ghost.

Expensive disk-repair software such as DiskWarrior *might* be able to repair it, or to retrieve the data. Given the clicking noise followed by silence, however, this is very unlikely. I wouldn't expect DiskWarrior to be successful.

Hard drives aren't repairable. The data can be retrieved by specialist businesses, but at significant cost.